# Remove all lines containing word NOT in dictionary

Tags: python, bash, unix

I have a dictionary of english words from `/usr/share/dict/words`

I have a huge file of sentences, line by line.  I'm trying to remove these weird sentences with foreign and out of vocabulary words by comparing against the dictionary.

```
Master.txt
Thanks to Your Greatness (谢谢你的美好)
Himatnagar has a small Railway Station
Pu$haz Ink
```

Can anyone help?  I tried using `diff` but it can only compare on word-level and not sentence-level

Comment: So `Himatnagar` is not in the dictionary words, do you still want to keep that sentence? Give samples of sentences you **do** want to keep.

Comment: Yeah, what do you wanna keep?  If you just want the Chinese characters gone, it'd probably be better to just target those directly instead of see if they are in an English dictionary.

Comment: In this case, I would keep none of the above sentences.  Sorry for the bad example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this in stages.

First, using `tr` (or maybe `sed` - slightly slower but more flexible, allows more precise removing of punctuation and so on), you chunk the sentence file into words:

```
tr " " "\n" < hugefile | sort | uniq | grep -v -F -f dictionary > blacklist.txt
```

Add `-i` option to `grep` for case insensitivity (see comment by Scott).

You then use `uniq` to gather unique words, and `grep -v -F -f dictionary` to get all words that are *not* in dictionary.

Once you have this "blacklist", you can request all the lines that *do not* contain any word in the blacklist itself. Again, you may want to consider upper/lower case, or not:

```
 grep -v -F -f blacklist.txt > goodlines.txt
```

In Python you can follow the same approach in a maybe more efficient way:

- load the dictionary into a list D.
- for each line of the input hugefile

  - split it into words and make this small list unique. Let this be W.
  - compute the intersection of the two lists W and D.
  - if its length is same as length of W, the line does not contain unknown words.

Comment: Words can be capitalized in `hugefile` but lower case in `dictionary`. So you'd want to unify that.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

**english-sentences-only.py**

```
input_filename = 'INPUT-FILE'
output_filename = 'OUTPUT-FILE'
dictionary_filename = '/usr/share/dict/words'
english_words = set(x[:-1].lower() for x in open(dictionary_filename).readlines())

def lines_with_only_english_words(input_filename):
    with open(input_filename) as fin:
        for line in fin:
            for w in line.split():
                if w.lower() not in english_words:
                    break
            else:
                yield line

with open(output_filename, 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(lines_with_only_english_words(input_filename))
```

```
python english-sentences-only.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{dict[$1]++;next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(!($i in dict))next}1' /usr/share/dict/words file
```

**Explanation**

The part in curly braces after FNR==NR applies only to the processing of the first file which is the dictionary. It saves each word in the dictionary in a hash called dict[]. The part in the second set of curly braces applies to the processing of your main input file. It cycles through all the words on the line and if any does not appear in the dictionary, the line is skipped, else the 1 at the end prints the line since it is true.